# Estimate new coordinates from given point and distance

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm dealing with an interesting problem that involves a degree of randomness, and requires backward calculation of coordinates from a vector of values in n-dimensional space, and distance to a new point.

So given a point vector $\vec{v_x} = (a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_n)$ where $a_i$ are its attributes or coordinates in $n$-dimensional space. Given an Euclidean distance value $g$, I need to generate a new vector $\vec{v_y}$ so that:

$$|\overrightarrow{v_x v_y}| \leq g$$
$$v_y = v_x + v_b$$
$$v_b = (b_1, b_2, b_3,...b_n)$$

$$v_y = (a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2, a_3+b_3 , ...a_n+b_n)$$

where $b_i$ is a non-zero parameter unique for every coordinate $a_i$. In other words, the distance between the two point vectors is smaller than a constant $g$.

I've tried looking into this issue and some answers in related questions point to the Gram matrix and the Distance matrix but it seemed like a specific solution to a different albeit related issue.

What I'm trying to do is generate various new point that are within a certain distance from the hyper-sphere around the first point, represented by the vectors above. I haven't been able to find a mathematical method or algorithm that deals with this correctly.

Comment: As described your problem is trivial: Just add a value smaller than $g$ to one of the coordinates. you get a new vector within $g$ of the old one. Maybe there are some requirements this new vector has to satisfy *other* than just being within $g$ of the old?

Comment: Ah yes, you're completely correct, I unintentionally omitted a crucial piece of information. The requirement is that every coordinate of the new vector needs to be adjusted by some small amount, not just one.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I edited the question now to better describe the problem and filled in the gaps I missed.

Comment: Still not hard. Just let $$b_i = \dfrac g{2^i}$$ Each is different, and the distance between the vectors will be $$\|v_b\| = \sqrt{\sum_i \frac{g^2}{4^{i}}} < \sqrt{ \frac{g^2}2} = \frac g{\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: Hey, to me it seems like wizardry :) Didn't think of that approach at all. It seems to work well, though I'm worried for large vectors (number of elements > 5000, which we're dealing with in our problem), $b_i$ will approach zero, so the first few elements will get a massive modification, while the rest will be barely modified at all. Though I assume that can be changed by modifying the $2^{i}$ term to something different, and further randomness by randomly arranging the order, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular example I gave is just convenient, not necessary. Choose any vector $\vec c = (c_1, c_2, c_3, \dots)$ that satisfies your distinctness needs without worrying about its size. Then rescale it: Choose some $A$ satisfying be some number smaller than $$0 < A < \frac{g}{\|\vec c\|} = \frac{g}{\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2 + \dots}}$$

Then just set $\vec v_b = A\vec c$. You will have $\|\vec v_b\| = A\|\vec c\| < g$ and you can set $\vec v_y = \vec v_x + \vec v_b$. You want to choose $A$ strictly smaller than $\frac{g}{\|\vec c\|}$ because if you try to make it equal, you risk rounding error giving you a resulting $\vec v_b$ whose length is slightly greater than $g$.

Your choice of $\vec c$ can keep all the values distinct without making some of them much larger or smaller than the others. You can generate the numbers randomly - though you should check the result to make sure it meets your distinctness needs.

Comment: Implemented it today and it works very well! Putting this here for those who may need this in the future in combination with a uniform distribution summing up to a specific value for our given vector c: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1